# Android Asmack xmpp login works only with my own facebook account

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, asmack

I'm developing an app that allows user to send private message to his/her facebook friends. To implement facebook login function I use the provided login button from facebook sdk (version 3.5). I'm using asmack-android-18 library to create an xmpp connection to chat.facebook.com. To login to chat.facebook.com for sending private message to user's friends I use the following line of code: 
`xmpp.login(applicationId, accessToken, "Application");` 
where xmpp is an instance of XMPPConnection. When login to the app using my own facebook account that I use as an administrator account on my facebook app account page. I put the right key hash on that page. The app is not in the sandbox mode. That why I can login into chat.facebook.com and send message to my friends. The very strange thing is that when login with other facebook. I asked my friend to use the app. He can login using his own facebook account. He sees his friend list. But he can not login into the chat.facebook.com, so he can't send message. The app works fine with only one facebook account as I mentioned before. I spent hours to search for a similar situation here on stackoverflow and everywhere possible on the internet including the facebook sdk official page. But I'm still stuck on this issue.

Edit. I see there is an option: Submit Items for Approval. Facebook says: "Some Facebook integrations require approval before public usage. Before submitting your app for review, please consult our App Center and Open Graph guidelines for more information about the review process." Maybe I must do that?

Any help or guide should be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In face when you creating the appllication id there is a option called sand box. Please enabble it to login to every one.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Actually as I mentioned in the question above. I have disabled sanbox mode. I know that the sandbox mode is for testing perpose. Facebook uses it to make sure your app is ok before publishing to the public. So now in my app dashboard it says "This app is live and available to all users".

Answer (score 0):

if you provide chat.facebook.com as a server and then try to log in with anyone credentials.
It will allow.